# use javascript function with ext.net control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ext.net

I wrote this function in javascript

```
function CheckBeforeAddNew(btnId, gridSelected) {
$(btnId).click(function () {
      for (var i in gridSelected) {
        return true;
      };
      Ext.Msg.alert('Add', 'Can not do without selected item');
      {
        return false;
      };
    });
};
```

and when I trying to make this function arrive on button click like this:

```
<ext:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddNewToMme" Cls="topButton" Text="Add new" Icon="Add" OnDirectClick="btnAddNewToMme_OnDirectClick">
                    <DirectEvents>
                        <Click Before="CheckBeforeAddNew('#<%= btnAddNewToMme.ClientID%>','<%=dlOuterObject.Grid_ClientID %>.selectedIds')"></Click>
                    </DirectEvents>
                </ext:Button>
```

I got error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(btnId).click(function () {`

**How can I invoke this function to make this work?**

**Edit:**
Of course I added file with this function to my `.aspx` like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Synchronization.js"></script>`

**Edit1:**
in firebug i can see before anything else

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>`
so jQuery is loaded correctly

**Edit2:**
I've made changes in my function which @geoffrey provide:

```
var CheckBeforeAddNew = function (gridSelected) {
for (var i in gridSelected) {
    return true;
}
Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Something wrong!');
return false;
```

};

But using of it

```
<ext:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddNewToMme" Cls="topButton" Text="Add new" Icon="Add" OnDirectClick="btnAddNewToMme_OnDirectClick">
                <DirectEvents>
                    <Click Before="return CheckBeforeAddNew('<%= dlOuterObject.Grid_ClientID %>.selectedIds');"></Click>
                </DirectEvents>
            </ext:Button>
```

I can't make this work:

```
if (grid.getSelectionModel().getCount() < 1) {
   Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please select an Item');

   return false;
}
```

my dlOuterObject is `UserControl` which contains grid. So any ideas how make it work?

Thanks for any help:)

Comment: Make sure Jquery is loaded correctly. You can use firebug and check if Jquery is referenced correctly.

Comment: yes jQuery is referenced correctly as well as `Synchronization.js` file

Comment: do I need make `e.preventdefault()` in `click()`method?

Comment: inspect the script tag with firebug, to see if the jQuery code really gets loaded.

Comment: Make sure you have loaded Jquery before synchronization.js file. The order which you load javascript files is important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your original code samples.

This `<%= btnAddNewToMme.ClientID%>` syntax does not work in ASP.NET markup configuration. You would need to use `<%# %>` DataBinding syntax.

Your `CheckBeforeAddNew` JavaScript function does not use the `btnId`, so you shouldn't need to pass this.

You don't need to use any jQuery either. All the functionality required is included in the `ExtJS` framework, which is already included on your `Page`.

Just pass an instance of the `GridPanel` into your JavaScript function, then encapsulate your logic for getting/checking the Selected Item count in the function.

Here's a fully functional sample demonstrating the scenario using Ext.NET 2.0. If you're using v1.x, the code `.Before` handler is basically the same, just the GridPanel Model config would be slightly different.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            var store = this.GridPanel1.GetStore();

            store.DataSource = this.Data;
            store.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private object[] Data
    {
        get
        {
            return new object[]
            {
                new object[] { "3m Co" },
                new object[] { "Alcoa Inc" },
                new object[] { "Altria Group Inc" },
                new object[] { "American Express Company" },
                new object[] { "American International Group, Inc." },
                new object[] { "AT&T Inc." },
                new object[] { "Boeing Co." },
                new object[] { "Caterpillar Inc." },
                new object[] { "Citigroup, Inc." },
                new object[] { "E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company" },
                new object[] { "Exxon Mobil Corp" },
                new object[] { "General Electric Company" }
            };
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Notify("Message", "Button1 Clicked").Show();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Simple Array Grid - Ext.NET Examples</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var checkSelected = function (grid) {
            if (grid.getSelectionModel().getCount() < 1) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please select an Item');

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:GridPanel 
        ID="GridPanel1"
        runat="server" 
        Title="Example" 
        Width="600" 
        Height="350">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store runat="server">
                <Model>
                    <ext:Model runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="company" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
        <ColumnModel>
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Company" DataIndex="company" Flex="1" />
            </Columns>            
        </ColumnModel>       
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:RowSelectionModel runat="server" Mode="Multi" />
        </SelectionModel>
        <Buttons>
            <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" Icon="Accept">
                <DirectEvents>
                    <Click OnEvent="Button1_Click" Before="return checkSelected(App.GridPanel1);" />
                </DirectEvents>
            </ext:Button>
        </Buttons>
    </ext:GridPanel>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've never use `<%# %>` syntax could you provide some example of using it?

Comment: The following Microsoft article should help get you started, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Comment: I've made edited my question for better understanding the problem:)